# Is possible to draw shapes in C# wpf (grid), if the grid is split by rows and cells, and each row contains a stackpanel inside?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, draw

When I try to draw a shape, like a line, is working only in the first StackPanel

```
Line myLine = new Line();
myLine.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
myLine.X1 = 1;
myLine.Y1 = 1;

myLine.X2 = 500;
myLine.Y2 = 50;
// myLine.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
// myLine.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
myLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
gridAreaFight.Children.Add(myLine);
```

And here is the picture of the grid.

[image]

I try to create a Tower Defense game, and I want the towers to attack (with lines/shapes) on the grid, but it seems the draw method is working only in my first stack panel image (see the picture, in the left corner top). Is there something I'm not doing right? Or I should use something else instead drawing method for my towers?

Comment: You probably need to set the Row/Column and/or RowSpan/ColumnSpan for your line eg for Row `Grid.SetRow(myLine, 1)`

Comment: Will lines always be horizontal or vertical? If you want a diagonal line. Ever.  Then another transparent control like a canvas on top of your grid is something to consider.

Comment: Thank you Rand Random, it worked after i've done a little research, Just added                                              
   Grid.SetRow/Column(myLine, maximumNumberOfRow/ColumnDefinition). Andy, the canvas option is not recommended in my case, I must click on the grid to place Towers, thank you for suggestion anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set row and column span for the line in order to draw it in whole available space. If you are drawing something on the grid without specific row and column, it defaults to column and row number 0.

```
        Line myLine = new Line();
        myLine.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
        Grid.SetRowSpan(myLine, n); // Here you are setting RowSpan. n-number of rows to span
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(myLine, n); // Here you are setting ColumnSpan. n-number of columns to span
        myLine.X1 = 1;
        myLine.Y1 = 1;

        myLine.X2 = 500;
        myLine.Y2 = 50;
        // myLine.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        // myLine.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        myLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
        area.Children.Add(myLine);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I suppose this is the only way ( at least the easy way ). It will be a little difficult to use this, because every tower will attack(with shapes like line or ellipse ) , and I need to know the coordinates and to check if at that coord there is a stackpanel, and if exists, i will use this code for stackpanel